# Plausibility of Low-Pressure Breathable Atmospheres?

Tags: planets, space-travel, atmosphere

My question is inspired by the fact that in the computer game Elite:Dangerous, the player's spacecraft is capable of landing on planets with "tenuous" atmospheres, measured as being 0.1 Earth atmospheric pressure or less. This leads me to wonder - is there any possible combination of gravities/atmospheric compositions/etc. that would create a world with a human-breathable atmosphere where these spacefarers could land?

Comment: Minimum necessary pressure is very obviously 0.2 atm pure oxygen. (Some mountain dwelling human populations may do well enough at 0.15 atm pure oxygen.) Famously, this was the atmosphere used by the [Apollo expediitions to the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_command_and_service_module). Minus one because I honestly don't see how somebody can be interested in space exploration seriously enough to plan to develop a story set in space, and at the same time not know what the Apollo astronauts breathed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the (rather implausible) atmosphere were *pure oxygen* and the explorer was a Sherpa or Quechua, acclimated for high elevation by being born around 5 km high, you'd still have to have a *minimum* of about 16 kPa (~150+ mBar) to have a breathable oxygen level.

For the much more plausible mix of oxygen and nitrogen, and reasonably fire-safe level of less than 30% oxygen, you'll need a minimum of about 400 mBar (roughly 40 kPa) even for your Sherpa/Quechua crew.  If the crew grew up at sea level, you'll want up to about 50% more than that, or around 600 mBar to give any level of comfort or long term survivability.

So, no, there's no gas mix that will make 0.1 atm (= 100 mBar or ~ 10 kPa) breathable for normal humans.